# How to make one sprite surround other in a 360 or 180

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm developing a game with some very basic ai. I just want srite B to surround in a perfect circle 360 degrees or half 180 in the update method the sprite A.

I tried to add and subtract x,y but I can't figure the angle part.

Any tips?

Comment: When you say surround do you mean orbit? As in you want the sprite to orbit the other sprite in a circle around it?

Comment: make sprite b a child of sprite a, set position of sprite b to other than 0,0 and change rotation of sprite a (run rotate action) .. observe the behavior. You can do this with any node.